# How to create multiple stop gradient fragment shader?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, gradient, interpolation

I'm trying to create an OpenGL ES 2.0 fragment shader that outputs multiple stop gradient along one axis. It should interpolate between multiple colors at points defined in percents.

I've achieved this by using `if`s the fragment shader, like this:

```
float y = gl_FragCoord.y;
float step1 = resolution.y * 0.20;
float step2 = resolution.y * 0.50;

if (y < step1) {
    color = white;
} else if (y < step2) {
    float x = smoothstep(step1, step2, y);
    color = mix(white, red, x);
} else {
    float x = smoothstep(step2, resolution.y, y);
    color = mix(red, green, x);
}
```

They say that branching in fragment shader can kill performance. Is there some clever trickery that can be used to interpolate between many values without using `if`s? Is it actually worth it (this is highly subjective, I know, but as rule of thumb)?

To illustrate my problem, full source (still short though) in this GLSL Sandbox link: http://glsl.heroku.com/e#8035.0

Comment: As I understand it, all cores on a GPU expect to perform the same operation at the same time. If you have branches, then there's a risk that different cores will need to perform different operations and therefore some of the cores effectively become blocked. This is what kills performance. It is indeed good practice to avoid branches in shaders.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to eliminate branches you can do following (taken from Heroku);

```
color = mix(white, red, smoothstep(step1, step2, y));
color = mix(color, blue, smoothstep(step2, step3, y));
color = mix(color, green, smoothstep(step3, resolution.y, y));
```

But I'm not sure at all whether this is any faster than if/elses or not.

Comment: This kind of answer I was actually looking for! If I'm having performance issues, I'll benchmark the performance of the methods then.