# JOGL overlapping?

Tags: opengl, jogl, overlap

So I'm starting to learn openGL via JOGL by doing a fractal image. However, I'm running into a problem.

I want it so that if a line drops below a portion of the screen, that part of the line should be hidden. I'm using the midpoint displacement method (where it bends the line). However, if I try and draw the line white when it drops below that portion of the screen, it paints the whole line section white rather than the specific part below the screen.

Although that's not quite what I want, I want it to be hidden when it overlaps a line that's on a lower plane than it, like a mountain.

http://i57.tinypic.com/2hplqfq.png

^ Example here.

Comment: You could accomplish that with shaders (with a fragment shader that changes the colour depending on the location), but seeing as you are just learning I guess you're not hitting shaders just yet. I could give an example of a shader if you wanted though?

Comment: If it could work, I'd like to look at it.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935117/how-to-create-multiple-stop-gradient-fragment-shader] and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428225/jogl-shader-programming] might help, they're not exactly what you want, also I'm no expert in JOGL